# Input and Output Impedances of Differential Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, differential, input-impedance, single-ended

I have this circuit that is used to convert an incoming analog differential input signal to a single ended signal. The differential input is connected at IN+, IN- and the output is taken from OUT.

I want to calculate input and output impedance's of this differential amplifier. How can I calculate it? Will it change if the power supply of the circuit is changed.

[image: Circuit]

Edit:
Simplified the circuit image for clarity.

Comment: Input Z is approximately 150 ohms and output Z is approximately 0 ohms (for non high frequency signals).

Comment: Can you show how you did this calculation? How does the frequency effects this calculation? The input is video signal. I am not sure about its frequency but i think it will be in the MHz range.

Comment: Input Z is largely determined by R60 and output Z (for moderate frequencies) is nearly always close to zero ohms for a decent op-amp working reasonably below the unity gain frequency.

Comment: @ alt-rose What if, at 100KHz, the Zout is +j10 ohms, and at 1,000Hz the Zout is +j100 ohms? would you notice the difference?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I have no idea how can I see the complex impedance values of +j10 or +j100. Can you elaborate on it?